# Behavior changes for updateViewConstraints in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, ios8

I notice some small graphical glitches while testing one of my app under iOS 8: some UIViews elements are not in the right place, others have not the right size.

In a first step, I use storyboard, Auto-Layout and constraints. Then I programmatically tune constraints to perfectly suits devices' screen size, using `updateViewConstraints`.

Perfect on iOS 7 but with some glitches on iOS8 as on following picture:
./Users/dominiquevial/Documents/Informatique/Dev/Novae Marathon/_log/captures/iOS8 - iPhone 6/pause.png

After investigation I found the problem: `updateViewConstraints` is not called. I don't understand why, maybe due to some optimizations...

Correcting this problem is easy :

1. use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in place of `updateViewConstraints`
2. or add call to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in `viewWillAppear`

Which way is the best one ?

Comment: Have the same problem, it looks like in iOS 7, in some cases, `updateViewConstraints` was called automatically, and not anymore in iOS8. My solution so far is to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in `viewDidLoad` manually.

Comment: Maybe `updateViewConstraints` is called more wisely in iOS 8 !

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the user can cause the views to enter an invalid state after the view appears, if so the first option. If this is not possible the second.

The less work your app has to do the better.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. What do you mean by _invalid state_ ?

Comment: Say if your views move around after they appear and when they reach a given point need to reset to there original position. If they are just static the second option should be fine.