# How to update size constraint of view based on size of superview using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want `self.boardView`, which is a subview of the controller's view, to be sized to the largest square that fits inside its superview. I set constraints in IB so that `self.boardView` is centered, and I have outlets for the width and height constraints. I am doing the following in the controller:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    const CGFloat W = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    const CGFloat H = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    const CGFloat S = (W < H) ? W : H;

    self.boardViewWidthConstraint.constant = S;
    self.boardViewHeightConstraint.constant = S;
}
```

The problem is that the controller's view bounds are *not* necessarily up to date (e.g., after a rotation). How/where can I set the constraints above based on the new size of the superview?

This may be a "chicken and egg" problem since the view sizes can't be updated until the new constraints are set, but I can't compute the constraints until the view sizes are updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are apparently changes in iOS8 how `updateViewConstraints` is called, see [Behavior changes for updateViewConstraints in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948001/behavior-changes-for-updateviewconstraints-in-ios-8).
I suggest trying

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    const CGFloat W = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    const CGFloat H = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    const CGFloat S = (W < H) ? W : H;

    self.boardViewWidthConstraint.constant = S;
    self.boardViewHeightConstraint.constant = S;
}
```

Comment: Actually, in an earlier version of my app, I created a subclass of `UIView` and simply set the subview frames directly in `layoutSubviews`. If I set constraints here, it still seems like I have the "chicken-and-egg" problem (I need view sizes to set constraints to compute the view sizes..).

Comment: According to <http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/> layoutsubvious IS called when the devices is rotated. So you should be able to get the new bounds in this method.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is called, but has the layout engine already sized all the views at this point? If not, then my values `W` and `H` are stale. If yes, then its too late to set constraints. Circular dependency.

Comment: To my understanding, layoutSubviews is called when all subviews of a view have to be arranged according to the current situation. At this point, thus, the bounds should reflect the new orientation of the device. If you set the new constraints here, they should be respected during the layout. Did you try it? You only had to change a few lines of code, and you can set a breakpoint in the method to check the bounds.

Comment: Yes, I tried  and it *does* work -- of course you have to change things a bit since `layoutSubviews` is a `UIView` method (not a `UIViewController` method). Of course I am now still confused -- how did it compute the width and height of the view since auto layout is needed to determine that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you have to define a UIView subclass to implement layoutSubviews. Anyway, when layoutSubviews is called on the viewControllers view, the bounds of this view must be known, otherwise the view could not layout its subviews. And if you overwrite its layoutSubviews, you can set there constraints for the subviews, before they are laid out. I hope this explanation is true...

Comment: I can see this works fine as long as all the constraints that are modified only effect the subviews (as in this case). If you modify a constraint that effects a parent view, then the whole layout cycle has to start over again -- or so it would seem.